# Sending Text and HTML Emails - Why is Gmail Always Picking Text Version?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, gmail, actionmailer, html-email

I'm sending some emails from my ASP.NET MVC application, using [ActionMailer.NET](http://actionmailer.net/).

Now, part of this process is sending both HTML **and** text versions of the message, to support text-only clients.

But what i'm seeing is that GMail is **always** picking the text version.

I tried Yahoo, and Yahoo is picking the HTML version correctly.

I tried dumbing down my HTML to nothing but a `<h1>` and a `<span>` tag, and GMail still picked the text version, which means there isn't a problem with the content of the HTML.

Is this expected behaviour?

Because when i send **only the HTML version**, GMail will show the HTML version correctly.

I've set the meta-tags in the HTML as follows:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Has anyone else encountered this behaviour, and found a solution?

Because as it stands, i'll probably have to send **only** the HTML version, so that GMail will render it, as too many of our clients use GMail.

Here's an example of basic HTML i'm trying to send:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>This is the heading</h1>
        <span>This is some text.</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

And GMail won't even allow that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess the first thing i should have checked is the ActionMailer.NET issues.

I did some Googling, and it didn't come up.

This issue was fixed 2 days ago, so getting the latest package fixed the problem.

https://bitbucket.org/swaj/actionmailer.net/issue/23/multipart-mail-problem

That issue was actually relating to Thunderbird, but guess GMail has a similar way of handling multipart emails.

Problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

Most web-based clients and desktop email clients ignore anything in the `<head>` tag of an email.

To send both html and text versions, you will need to construct the mail message properly - have two mime chunks.

Show us the full code you are using to construct your email.

Comment: It's all in the ActionMailer.NET built-in code, so i don't set any headers, etc. I'm just curious as to why Yahoo works, Gmail doesnt. Same message.

Comment: When you are constructing your MailMessage object, use the MailMessage.AlternateViews property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.alternateviews.aspx

Comment: nevermind, i found the problem, see my answer above. Thanks for your help anyway (+1)